# Можно ли откатить ветку в GitLab на день назад?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit

Всем привет, я случайно удалил кучу файлов на ветке GitLab. Можно ли откатить ветку полностью на какое-то время? Например, на вчерашнее состояние?

Comment: а что вам мешает?

Comment: нельзя откатить на "вчерашнее состояние". Можно откатить на какой-то конкретный коммит. С вопросом "как это сделать" обращаться к справке гитлаба или учебнику гита. Это самые азы.

Comment: @Эникейщик чой-то? `git reset @{yesterday}` =)

Comment: Ну ладно, утрирую. Это конечно будет какой-то конкретный вчерашний коммит (надо посмотреть в документации как гит его выбирает)

Comment: @AlexeyTen а где про такое почитать, что-то не находится ничего

Comment: @Эникейщик [git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrefnamegtltdategtemegemmasteryesterdayememHEAD5minutesagoem)

Comment: [git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от того, когда вы делали commitы. Вы можете откатывать, но точка отката будет не время/дата, а commit`ы. Именно во время commita git делает "снимок". Вы можете откатить до любого commita как все файлы (команда reset), так и один файл (команда checkout). В вашем случае вероятно подойдет команда git reset